# ssh key gitlab CI .gitlab-CI.yml setup fail

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitlab-ci

$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
Enter passphrase for (stdin): ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

i set up ssh key without any password but then i got this error asking for passphrase.. did googling and try all the tips but still not working.. most googled result is error on  enter passphrase for **/dev/fd/63'** .

can anyone help me? for the first time trying to setup auto deploy using gitlab.
server and local os using ubuntu

Comment: Most likely your `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable does not have the key in the correct format.

Comment: Just copy after and before of the start and end comment of the private key and store into gitlab ci/cd variable right?

Comment: I just made it, i put it here in case anyone meet same problem.. The private and public key is from local machine not from the server gitlab pointed to.. Feeling dumb on this mistake

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the same setup and error message when following [gitlab's official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor). My mistake was that I *thought* the ssh key was set up with no passphrase but in fact *it was*. After regenerating a new set of keys, this time with no passphrase, then ssh-add stopped asking for one...

Note: writing the key to a file with e.g.

```
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

was of course of no help in my case...